Rewriting the GetAsync method using IAsyncEnumerable in Dapper
I just learned about QueryUnbufferedAsync and IAsyncEnumerable in here https://www.learndapper.com/dapper-query/selecting-unbuffered-async
and wanted to use it in my own data service class but I am doing something wrong as this is not compiling. I think I am messing up the return data types but I couldn't figure out the way to use it.
Here is my code:
private async Task<T> GetAsync2<T>(Func<DbConnection, Task<T>> operation)
{
    if (operation is null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(operation)); }

    await using DbConnection myCon = new SnowflakeDbConnection("myConnectionString");
    await myCon.OpenAsync();

    var result = await databaseOperation(myCon);

    return result;
}

public async Task<IAsyncEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync<T>(string sqlSelect) => await GetAsync2(conn => conn.QueryUnbufferedAsync<T>(sqlSelect));

This is the build error I get:

The type arguments for method 'GetAsync2(Func<DbConnection, Task>)' cannot be inferred from the usage.


QueryUnbufferedAsync returns an IAsyncEnumerable. It's not async Task<IAsyncEnumerable because IAsyncEnumerable is already async-friendly.
So you need another overload that accepts a non-Task delegate.
However, because of the fact it's unbuffered, you can't close the connection until the data is read. Therefore you need (and should anyway) rely on Dapper to open and close the connection once the data is fully read. Dapper can handle this as long as the connection was closed when you started the operation.
private T GetFromDb<T>(Func<DbConnection, T> operation)
{
    // do NOT add using
    var myCon = new SnowflakeDbConnection("myConnectionString");
    var result = operation(myCon);
    return result;
}

public IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetAllAsync<T>(string sqlSelect) =>
    GetFromDb(conn => conn.QueryUnbufferedAsync<T>(sqlSelect));

However at this point I'm not sure what you gain by messing with delegates.

No it isn't missing. The delegate does not return a Task as QueryUnbufferedAsync doesn't.

quite right I originally had it opening the connection

Getting there thanks, used your suggestion but getting compile error on GetAllAsync saying "Cannot return a value from an iterator. Use the yield return statement to return a value, or yield break to end the iteration."

I changed it to this below, now the compile error is gone. Now trying to figure out how to actually use it in the consumer methods.
public async IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetAllAsync<T>(string sqlSelect)         {             yield return (T)GetFromDb(conn => conn.QueryUnbufferedAsync<T>(sqlSelect));         }

No don't do that, use my code instead. Sorry I had an extraneous async there.

Thanks, will do. I get back to it later but I will mark yours as answer. Thanks for helping out
